# (WPF) How to set up a TreeView by is-a rather than has-a

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

From what I've seen, TreeViews usually expect models to use have has-a relationship, where the parent node has references to all of it's children. Ex: an ExampleModel has a collection of ExampleChildModel. In the TreeView, ExampleChildModel nodes get shown as children of ExampleModel nodes. In my case, I need to create a hierarchy defined by a property on ExampleModel and there is no ExampleChildModel.

To be a little more concrete, the problem I'm facing is: I need to create something that displays a collection of items. I think a TreeView is the way to go, but maybe I'm wrong. Each item has a string Grouping property, a string DisplayName property, and an int Ordinality property (as well as some other properties that are not relevant to this problem):

```
public class AModelWithACollection
{
    private ObservableCollection<StrippedDownModel> _collection;
    public ObservableCollection<StrippedDownModel> Collection
    {
        get => _collection;
        set => SetProperty(ref _collection, value);
    }

    //Lots of other properties that don't need to be shown in the TreeView
}

public class StrippedDownModel
{
    private string _grouping;
    public string Grouping
    {
        get => _grouping;
        set => SetProperty(ref _grouping, value);
    }

    private string _displayName;
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get => _displayName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _displayName, value);
    }

    private int _ordinality;
    public int Ordinality
    {
        get => _oridnality;
        set => SetProperty(ref _ordinality, value);
    }

    //Lots of other properties that don't need to be shown in the TreeView
}
```

Part of the xaml would probably look something like:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=InstanceOfAModelWithACollection.Collection}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <!-- Not really what the DataTemplates here would look like -->
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

If I had a collection of 5 StrippedDownModel objects and 3 of them had Grouping set to "Group 1" and two had Grouping set to "Group 2", I'd expect a tree with 2 nodes named "Group 1" and "Group 2" with 3 and 2 children, respectively. I'd also want the child nodes to be ordered by the Ordinality property:

```
Group 1
    Object 1
    Object 2
    Object 3

Group 2
    Object 4
    Object 5
```

How do I create this? All the examples I've seen so far use the has-a relationship I described initially.

One thought I had was to transform StrippedDownModel into something that used a has-a relationship. Ex: make NewParentModel and NewChildModel and run AModelWithACollection.Collection through some transform that would create instances of those new models and then bind to that. I'd have to think of some way to make changes to that transformed collection also get reflected in the original Collection, since that original model will be used to create a dto that gets sent up to a back end to be written to a database.

I'd prefer a way to just bind to AModelWithACollection.Collection though, so I wouldn't have to worry about transforms and keeping two models in sync.

EDIT:
For anyone encountering the same problem: The suggestion that @RolandJS posted works well. I wasn't a fan of the group headers causing some cognitive dissonance with the DataGrid headers though. I ended up changing my model to be more like the standard model a TreeView would use. It's now has-a, so it has a collection of collections of StrippedDownModels, where the parent collections are the groups.

Comment: Maybe a DataGrid with sorting and grouping is what you are looking for. See this doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @RolandJS That seems a lot better at first glance. I'll try it out. Thanks for the tip.